# Facebook application problem with php-sdk-2.1

Tags: facebook

I have read the facebook documentation. But I am unable to understand how to get the correct permission for to accessing the status table to get user statuses.

Please Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

user_status

Here's a list of all extended permissions:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

-Roozbeh